# Embed terminal in a Gnome panel

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I think it would be nice to have a command line that's always visible (and doesn't clutter the screen). GUIs like `gvim` and `ooffice` are quicker to open from terminal, since that allows you to skip having to navigate to your file(s) from within the gui.

Is there any way in Gnome to embed a terminal in either of the top or bottom panels?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need something like [Guake](http://guake.org/)

Comment: Looks good, will try this when I get home.

Comment: I'm in love with it already

Comment: Glad it worked out for you!